# Why this Artin ring is simple?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Suppose we have a non-commutative left Artin ring $R$, such that the subring generated by *any* nonzero two-sided ideal together with the unity is $R$ itself. I read that $\mathrm{Z}(R)$, which is the center of $R$, forms an integral domain, but why is this true? And how can one proceed to deduce that $R$ is simple? I tried to use DCC on the sets of all two-sided ideals to go further, but don’t see why this implies there can only be extremal two-sided ideals in this case. Any hints on this?

Comment: Are you sure you’ve stated the question correctly? What about $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @Jeremy Richard Whoops, I forget to say $R$ is not commutative. Otherwise you already provide a good counter example.

Comment: The condition here , as in your other question, that ideals generated “together with 1” are the whole ring is equally fishy here.  Clarify please in both places

Comment: The following condition is copied from my textbook: Suppose  that for each non-zero two-sided ideal $$, the subring generated by $∪{1} $is $R$. I actually don’t see how this is different from what I wrote. @rschwieb

Comment: @GK1202 when you say a subset generates the ring, everyone is going to think it means “as an R submodule”, you you are saying you intended “as a ring”. This is a vital piece of information that is causing confusion, so please add it to the post body.

Comment: Now, using you hypotheses now, and selecting the zero ideal, you have that $1$ generates the entire ring, therefore it is commutative. this is a contradiction to resolve.

Comment: What textbook? ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: It’s a Chinese book. I translate the question here. But I think the condition only holds for non-zero two sided ideals? I fixed it in the post. @rschwieb

Comment: @GK1202 can you please indicate the author and title? It seems like an offbeat approach that I would be interested in attaching a name to.

Comment: Okay, the name is $Advanced Algebra$, the author is Yang Fan. I’m not sure whether you can find information about it, because it’s a textbook written by a professor in my university. My version is only a pre-print PDF.@rschwieb

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how to approach the result?@rschwieb

Comment: @GK1202 I’ve thought about it a little, but haven’t seen the solution. It is an unusual scenario for a simple problem like this one, and I don’t see the trick yet. That’s why I was asking about the source.

Comment: Do you think the fact the center of this ring forms a domain helps the proof? Since the original question is two part, the first part ask to show the center forms a domain. But I actually don’t see how this helps, maybe they are unrelated. @rschwieb

Comment: @rschwieb I updated the post, now two parts are shown together.

Comment: @GK1202 Thanks: I think the question is clear now. Unfortunately I forgot to retract a close vote until too late, and someone finished the job. I've nominated for re-opening.

Answer (score 2):

Let $R$ be left artinian such that, for all non-zero two-sided ideals $I$, the subring generated by 1 and $I$ is all of $R$. We will describe all such $R$, including the commutative ones.

Write $J$ for the Jacobson radical of $R$, a two-sided ideal. Suppose first that $J^2$ is non-zero. Then $R$ is generated as a ring by 1 and $J^2$, so $R/J^2$ is generated by 1, and hence is a quotient of $\mathbb Z$. In particular, $J/J^2$ is generated by the image of some integer $a$, so by Nakayama's Lemma $J=Ra$, and hence, using the nilpotency of $J$, we see that $\mathbb Z$ surjects onto $R$. Thus $R=\mathbb Z/n$ for some integer $n$.

Otherwise $J^2=0$. Assume $J\neq0$. Then $R$ is generated by 1 and $J$, so $R/J$ is generated by 1, so is a quotient of $\mathbb Z$. If the image of some $a\in\mathbb Z$ is non-zero and in $J$, then $R$ is generated by $1$ and $Ra$, so by 1, and hence is a quotient of $\mathbb Z$.

Otherwise, the image $A$ of $\mathbb Z$ intersects $J$ trivially, and $R=A\oplus J$. If $e\in A$ is a non-trivial idempotent, then $R$ is generated by 1 and $Re$, so $J=Je$. Similarly $J=J(1-e)$, so $J=0$, a contradiction. Thus $A=\mathbb Z/p$ for some prime $p$. Taking any non-zero $t\in J$ we see that $R=(\mathbb Z/p)[t]/(t^2)$.

Finally, if $J=0$, then $R$ is semisimple artinian, so a product of matrices over division rings. If $R=A\times B$ is a proper product, then $R$ is generated as a ring by 1 and either $A$ or $B$. Thus both $A$ and $B$ are quotients of $\mathbb Z$ by square-free integers. This holds for any such decomposition, so either $R=\mathbb Z/m$ with $m$ square-free, or else $R=(\mathbb Z/p)^2$ for some prime $p$. Note that up to now, all such $R$ are commutative.

The only other case is when $R$ is a matrix ring over a division ring, and so simple. In particular, every such non-commutative $R$ is simple artinian.

In summary, then only such rings are
$$ \mathbb Z/n, \quad (\mathbb Z/p)[t]/(t^2), \quad (\mathbb Z/p)^2, \quad \mathbb M_r(D) $$
with $p,n,r\in\mathbb N$ and $p$ prime, and $D$ a division ring.

Comment: In your third paragraph, explicitly how do you get from "$R$ being generated by $1_R$ and $kR$" to "so $R$ is being generated by $1_R$"? You have the relation $R=\mathbb{Z}_R+kR$ with $kR \subseteq \mathrm{Rad}(R)$, however it is not clear what justification you could bring for getting rid of the summand $kR$ in the above relation....especially since $\mathbb{Z}_R$ is not an ideal of any kind...

Comment: We have $a\in J$ non-zero for some integer $a$. Thus $a$ is central, and $Ra$ is a proper non-zero two-sided ideal, so $R$ is generated by 1 and $Ra$. If $x\in J$, then $ax\in J^2$, so is zero. Thus every element of $Ra$ is in fact in the image of $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: In other words, explicitly put, from the relation $R=\mathbb{Z}_R+kR$ we obtain upon multiplying by $k_R\colon=k1_R$ that $kR=(k\mathbb{Z})_R+k^2R$, where $k^2_A$ is in the square of the radical and thus null. This means that $kR=(k\mathbb{Z})_R$ which substituted in the original relation entails $R=\mathbb{Z}_R$. This would have deserved to be neatly presented, in explicit detail.

Comment: The “finally” paragraph is quite an ingenuous way to eliminate non-prime semisimple rings.  Kudos for tackling the problem considering commutative rings too.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I was working on.  Let $R$ be a right ring such that $1\cdot \mathbb Z+I=R$ for every nonzero ideal $I$, such that $R$ is not commutative.

> Lemma 1: under the conditions above, there is no nonzero element $x$ such that $x\mathbb Z$ is an ideal of $R$.

Proof: if $x\mathbb Z$ were a two-sided ideal, $1\cdot\mathbb Z+x\mathbb Z$ would be commutative, contradicting our standing hypotheses.

> Lemma 2: under the conditions above, if $I$ is a nonzero ideal, $I^2\neq \{0\}$.

Proof: if $I^2=\{0\}$, then $R=1\cdot \mathbb Z+I$ is commutative, so the square of $I$ must be nonzero.

> Proposition:  The center of $R$ is a domain.

Proof: If $xy=0$, and $x,y$ are nonzero elements of the center of $R$, then from $R=1\cdot \mathbb Z+(y)$, we learn $xR=x\mathbb Z$. Since the right hand side is manifestly a nonzero ideal, the Lemma 1 above contradicts this. Therefore there is no such pair $x,y$, and the center is a domain.

> Proposition: $R$ is simple Artinian

Proof: it suffices to show that $R$ is prime, i.e. there are no nonzero ideals $A,B$ such that $AB=\{0\}$.  Suppose two such ideals existed.  Since $(BA)^2=\{0\}$, we see by Lemma 2 that $BA=\{0\}$ as well.

Now let $a$ be a nonzero element of $A$.  From $R=1\cdot \mathbb Z +B$ we learn both $aR=a\mathbb Z$ and $Ra=a\mathbb Z$. Therefore $aR=Ra=a\mathbb Z$ is a nonzero ideal of $R$, something prevented by the Lemma 1 above.

Therefore $R$ is a right Artinian prime ring, which is well-known to be a simple Artinian ring.

---

If one does not recall the proof that a right Artinian prime ring is simple, we could also say that $R$ is right Artinian and semiprime, hence semisimple. It would remain to show that it is simple, and this would follow from a similar argument about existence of two ideals $A,B$ such that $AB=BA=\{0\}$.

Comment: It's also interesting to note -- looking at your very succinct proof -- how the investigation of the properties of the centre is a bit of a red herring, and far from being indispensible to the general argument. You have succeeded in effectively showing that any non-commutative ring satisfying the additional generation assumption is necessarily prime, which will of course entail the integrity of the centre. Silly me for being taken in by the apparent suggestion to first go through the centre in order to come to a conclusion about the whole ring...

Comment: @ΑΘΩ Yes well there’s no telling how the author thought of it.  Maybe it was indispensable to him/her.  Or maybe they thought the problems could be listed together since they are related somewhat by the lemmas I cooked up.  I made the comment before that this seems like an unusual approach, somewhat home-baked if you will.  Nice for a problem, but somehow divorced from mainstream theory.

Comment: Indeed, it's a quirky (let's say extravagant) approach to assume the particular generation condition as a starting point. That alone is strong enough an assumption to allow one to plow through the structural description of such rings as you did, by focusing on issues of (semi)primality, without having to take a detour through the centre. Centre which is comically enough not at all central for the argumentation of this problem!

Answer (score 0):

After having needed to spend a bit of time in order for things to come to light, may I say that this is quite a lovely problem and may I convey my regards to your professor for having included it in his textbook.

Let us assume a left Artinian, non-commutative ring $A$ such that for every *nonzero bilateral* (I dislike the English terminology of "two-sided") ideal we have $A=[I \cup \{1_A\}]_{\mathrm{Ann}}$, where for arbitrary subset $X \subseteq A$ I use the notation $[X]_{\mathrm{Ann}}$ to refer to the subring generated by $X$ in $A$. Let us remark that for any bilateral ideal $I \leqslant_{\mathrm{b}} A$ we have the relation $[I \cup \{1_A\}]_{\mathrm{Ann}}=I+\mathbb{Z}_A$, where I have used the abbreviation $\mathbb{Z}_A\colon=\mathbb{Z}1_A\colon=\{n1_A\}_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$ (on the same note let us also introduce $n_A\colon=n1_A$ for arbitrary integer $n \in \mathbb{Z}$).

We seek to prove that $A$ is simple under these conditions and we shall proceed in the following sequence:

> 1. Introducing the abbreviation $C\colon=\mathrm{Z}(A)$ for the centre of $A$, we first argue that $C$ is a field.

Since $A$ is non-commutative it is in particular nonzero, which means $0_A \neq 1_A$ and therefore $C$ is also nonzero. Given arbitrary ring $R$ we shall write $\mathrm{U}(R)$ for the subset of units of $R$ and similarly $R^{\times}\colon= R \setminus \{0_R\}$. For arbitrary subset $X \subseteq R$ we recall the *left* and *right* annihilators $\mathrm{Ann}_{\mathrm{s}}(X)\colon=\{t \in A \mid tX \subseteq \{0_R\}\}$ respectively $\mathrm{Ann}_{\mathrm{d}}(X)=\{t \in A \mid Xt \subseteq \{0_R\}\}$, remarking that left (right) annihilators are always left (right) ideals: $\mathrm{Ann}_{\mathrm{s}}(X) \leqslant_{\mathrm{s}} R$ respectively $\mathrm{Ann}_{\mathrm{d}}(X) \leqslant_{\mathrm{d}} R$. In the particular case when $X \subseteq \mathrm{Z}(R)$ is a *central* subset it is easily seen that the two lateral annihilators coincide and are both a *bilateral* ideal of $R$: $\mathrm{Ann}_{\mathrm{s}}(X)=\mathrm{Ann}_{\mathrm{d}}(X) \leqslant_{\mathrm{b}} R$.

We first establish the following characterisation: $z \in \mathrm{U}(C) \Leftrightarrow \mathrm{Ann}_{\mathrm{s}}(z)=\{0_A\}$ (a central element is invertible if and only if it is *cancellable*). Indeed, the implication $z \in \mathrm{U}(C) \Rightarrow \mathrm{Ann}_{\mathrm{s}}(z)=\{0_A\}$ is a particular case of the more general implication $x \in \mathrm{U}(A) \Rightarrow \mathrm{Ann}_{\mathrm{s}}(x)=\mathrm{Ann}_{\mathrm{d}}(x)=\{0_A\}$, relation which is valid in *any* ring without imposing any supplementary hypotheses.

As for the converse implication, we turn to the left Artinian nature of $A$ by considering the decreasing sequence of principal left (they are actually bilateral) ideals $\left(Az^n\right)_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$ and inferring the existence of $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $Az^k=Az^{k+1}$, which further entails the existence of $x \in A$ such that $z^k=z^{k+1}x$ or equivalently $(1_A-zx)z^k=0_A$ and thus $1_A-zx \in \mathrm{Ann}_{\mathrm{s}}\left(z^k\right)$. In general, for arbitrary $y \in A$ it is elementary that $\mathrm{Ann}_{\mathrm{s}}(y)=\{0_A\}$ entails $\mathrm{Ann}_{\mathrm{s}}\left(y^n\right)=\{0_A\}$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ (if $y$ has a zero left annihilator then the group endomorphism of $(A, +)$ given by *right* multiplication with $y$ is injective, property which is preserved by all the powers of this endomorphism in the ring $\mathrm{End}_{\mathbf{Gr}}((A, +))$, powers which are none other than the endomorphisms given by right multiplication with $y^n$ for generic $n \in \mathbb{N}$). We thus infer that $zx=xz=1_A$, which means that $z \in \mathrm{U}(A) \cap \mathrm{Z}(A)=\mathrm{U}(C)$ (recall that in general for *any* monoid $M$ the equality $\mathrm{U}(\mathrm{Z}(M))=\mathrm{U}(M) \cap \mathrm{Z}(M)$ holds, since indeed any central element of $M$ which is a unit *of* $M$ will necessarily have a central inverse, rendering it into a unit of the centre).

Having obtained the above characterisation, let us further establish the relation $z=0_A \Leftrightarrow z \in C \wedge \mathrm{Ann}_{\mathrm{s}}(z) \neq \{0_A\}$. The $\Rightarrow$ direction is clear, so we focus on the converse, considering an arbitrary central element $z \in C$ whose (left...) annihilator $I\colon=\mathrm{Ann}_{\mathrm{s}}(z)$ is nonzero. As we have already remarked, $I \leqslant_{\mathrm{b}} A$ is in this case a bilateral ideal and as it is nonzero we gather that $A=I+\mathbb{Z}_A$ by virtue of our very particular assumption. This immediately entails the description $Az=\left(I+\mathbb{Z}_A\right)z=Iz+\mathbb{Z}z=\mathbb{Z}z$, which means that any element in the principal (left...) ideal generated by $z$ is actually an *integer* multiple of $z$. Let us now additionally assume that $z \neq 0_A$ and derive from this a contradiction. If indeed $z \neq 0_A$ then $z \in Az \leqslant_{\mathrm{b}} A$, in other words $Az$ is a nonzero bilateral ideal (left ideals generated by central subsets are automatically bilateral). The particular assumption of our problem once again applies to the conclusion that $A=Az+\mathbb{Z}_A=\mathbb{Z}z+\mathbb{Z}_A$, which further entails the commutativity of $A$ thus contradicting the hypothesis. It follows that with necessity $z=0_A$, under the above assumptions.

Hence, an arbitrary central element $z \in C$ either has nontrivial (left...) annihilator - in which case it is $0_A$ - or a trivial one, in which case it is a unit of $C$. This establishes $C$ as a field.

> 2. We now argue that $A$ is a simple ring, for which it will suffice to show that its *Jacobson radical* $R\colon=\mathrm{Rad}(A)$ is null.

Indeed, having established the fact that $R=\{0_A\}$ we recall the **general property of any left Artinian ring of having a semisimple quotient by its radical**. It follows from one of the Wedderburn structure theorems that $A/\{0_A\} \approx A \ (\mathbf{Ann})$ is semisimple and thus isomorphic to the direct product of a *finite* family $S$ - indexed by $\Lambda$ - of *nonzero simple* rings. This entails that the centre $C$ is isomorphic to the direct product of the family $(\mathrm{Z}(S_{\lambda}))_{\lambda \in \Lambda}$ of centres. By virtue of another one of the Wedderburn structure theorems, it can be easily inferred that the centre of a nonzero simple ring is necessarily a field. Combining this with the fact that $C$ is itself a field and hence a nonzero domain, we gather that $|\Lambda|=1$, in other words the direct product isomorphically expressing $A$ must consist of precisely one factor (the case $|\Lambda| \geqslant 2$ would contradict the integrity of $C$ whereas $\Lambda=\varnothing$ is prohibited by our previous observation that since $A$ is noncommutative it is in particular nonzero).

Let us proceed by *Reductio ad Absurdum* and assume that $R \neq \{0_A\}$. We first remark that under this hypothesis it is impossible that $\mathrm{char}\ C=0$. Indeed, if this were the case then $2_A \neq 0_A$. Since $R \leqslant_{\mathrm{b}} A$ is nonzero we gather that $A=R+\mathbb{Z}_A$ and as $C$ is a field we can claim that $\frac{1}{2_A} \in A$, whence there must exist $a \in R$ and $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $\frac{1}{2_A}=a+k_A$. This equation leads to $a=-k_A+\frac{1}{2_A} \in C^{\times}=\mathrm{U}(C)$ and signifies that the proper ideal $R$ would contain a unit, clearly an absurd situation (the hypothesis that $C$ is of characteristic $0$ is the one which justifies the assertion that $k_A \neq \frac{1}{2_A}$, equivalent to $(2k-1)_A \neq 0_A$).

Since $C$ is a field, we must have $\mathrm{char}\ C=p$ for a certain (strictly positive) prime number $p$. This means that $A$ has a canonical (associative and unitary) $\mathbb{Z}_p$ - algebra structure, where I am using the notation $\mathbb{Z}_r\colon=\mathbb{Z}/r\mathbb{Z}$ for arbitrary $r \in \mathbb{N}$. From the particular assumption in the hypothesis we gather that given any *proper nonzero* bilateral ideal $I \leqslant_{\mathrm{b}} A$, we have $A=I+(\mathbb{Z}_p)1_A$, where the sum on the right-hand side is *direct*: indeed, $I \cap \left(\mathbb{Z}^{\times}_p\right)1_A \subseteq I \cap \mathrm{U}(A)=\varnothing$ whence it follows that $I \cap (\mathbb{Z}_p)1_A=\{0_A\}$. From this we infer that $\mathrm{codim}^{A}_{\mathbb{Z}_p}I=\mathrm{dim}_{\mathbb{Z}_p}(A/I)=1$, in other words any nonzero proper bilateral ideal of $A$ is a *hyperplane* in the $\mathbb{Z}_p$-vector space structure subjacent to the algebra structure introduced above.

Let $\mathscr{Id}_{\mathrm{b}}(A)$ denote the set of all bilateral ideals of $A$, $\mathscr{I}\colon=\mathscr{Id}_{\mathrm{b}}(A) \setminus \{A\}$ and $\mathscr{I}’\colon=\mathscr{I} \setminus \{\{0_A\}\}$. As $A$ is nonzero we clearly have $\mathscr{I} \neq \varnothing$. Bearing in mind the general relation $R \subseteq \displaystyle \bigcap \mathrm{Max}\left(\mathscr{I}\right)$ ($\mathscr{I}$ is considered implicitly ordered by inclusion and the syntax $\mathrm{Max}$ refers to the collection of maximal elements with respect to this ordered set, in other words the collection of all *maximal* bilateral ideals), we infer that $\mathscr{I}’ \neq \varnothing$ (otherwise we would have $\mathscr{I}=\{\{0_A\}\}$, $\mathrm{Max}\left(\mathscr{I}\right)=\{0_A\}$ and eventually $R \subseteq \{0_A\}$).

It is also an elementary fact that the ordered set $\mathscr{I}$ is inductive and therefore admits at least a maximal element, say $M \in \mathrm{Max}\left(\mathscr{I}\right)$. It is clear that $M \neq \{0_A\}$, for assuming the contrary would once again entail $\mathscr{I}=\{\{0_A\}\}$, situation which we have already ruled out as impossible under the given assumptions. Since $M, R \in \mathscr{I}’$ we have that $M$ and $R$ are both $\mathbb{Z}_p$ - hyperplanes of $A$, according to one of the previous observations. Since $R \subseteq M$, we thus gather that $R=M$, meaning that the Jacobson radical $R$ is a *maximal* bilateral ideal. Since $R$ is at the same time included in every maximal bilateral ideal, we infer that $\mathrm{Max}\left(\mathscr{I}\right)=\{R\}$.

Since any proper bilateral ideal is included in a certain maximal bilateral ideal (by virtue of the same token of inductivity of $\mathscr{I}$ ordered by inclusion), the existence of just one maximal bilateral ideal means that $A$ actually has $R$ as a *maximum* proper bilateral ideal, symbolically $R=\max \mathscr{I}$. Thus, if we furthermore consider an arbitrary $I \in \mathscr{I}’$ we gather that $I \subseteq R$ and $I$, $R$ are both $\mathbb{Z}_p$ - hyperplanes of $A$. Once again, this entails $I=R$ and signifies that we actually have the relation $\mathscr{I}=\{\{0_A\}, R\}$.

Let us however keep in mind another **general property of left Artin rings, namely that they have nilpotent Jacobson radicals**. I will use the notation $I^{.n}$ to refer to the power of exponent $n \in \mathbb{N}$ of the bilateral ideal $I$ within the multiplicative monoid $(\mathscr{Id}_{\mathrm{b}}(A), \bullet)$. In our case, since $R^{.2} \in \mathscr{I}$ we have either $R^{.2}=\{0_A\}$ or $R^{.2}=R$. The latter option would mean that $R$ is at the same time a nonzero idempotent as well as a nilpotent element, which constitutes a contradiction. This leaves the only possible option $R^{.2}=\{0_A\}$.

The above finding means in particular that $R^{(2)}=RR=\{0_A\}$ and - together with the relation $A=R+\mathbb{Z}_A$ - allows us to infer that $R \subseteq \mathrm{C}_A(R)$, in other words $R$ centralises itself. As it is also obvious that $R \subseteq \mathrm{C}_A(\mathbb{Z}_A)$, taking into account the relation $A=R+\mathbb{Z}_A$ we easily gather that $A \subseteq \mathrm{C}_A(A)=\mathrm{Z}(A)$, contradicting the restriction that $A$ is not commutative. This contradiction is caused by the assumption $R\neq \{0_A\}$ and signifies that indeed $R=\{0_A\}$, as we had set out to prove.

Our argument thus comes to an end.